# Deploying to New Internal Maven Repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a completely empty file system set up as an internal Maven Repository.
I am trying to deploy to this Repository via SFTP.

This is the first jar that I am deploying to the Repository and as I understand it is is possible to point it at a blank writable directory and maven will build up all the correct files.

When running the deploy target I get the following errors:

```
[INFO] Downloading: scpexe://mvn.metcarob.com:7456/public/metcarob/com/BobDiary/BobDiary/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to ssh-repository (scpexe://mvn.metcarob.com:7456/public): Exit code: 1 - Connected to mvn.metcarob.com.
File "/public/metcarob/com/BobDiary/BobDiary/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml" not found.

org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to ssh-repository (scpexe://mvn.metcarob.com:7456/public): Exit code: 1 - Connected to mvn.metcarob.com.
File "/public/metcarob/com/BobDiary/BobDiary/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml" not found.

    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.MetadataTransportListener.transferFailed(MetadataTransportListener.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.upload(DefaultDeployer.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:413)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Exit code: 1 - Connected to mvn.metcarob.com.
File "/public/metcarob/com/BobDiary/BobDiary/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml" not found.

    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.external.ScpExternalWagon.executeScpCommand(ScpExternalWagon.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.external.ScpExternalWagon.get(ScpExternalWagon.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run(WagonTransporter.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTransporter.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get(WagonTransporter.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
    ... 32 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.058 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-16T16:25:36+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/630M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project BobDiary: Failed to retrieve remote metadata metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to ssh-repository (scpexe://mvn.metcarob.com:7456/public): Exit code: 1 - Connected to mvn.metcarob.com.
[ERROR] File "/public/metcarob/com/BobDiary/BobDiary/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml" not found.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project BobDiary: Failed to retrieve remote metadata metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to ssh-repository (scpexe://mvn.metcarob.com:7456/public): Exit code: 1 - Connected to mvn.metcarob.com.
File "/public/metcarob/com/BobDiary/BobDiary/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml" not found.

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to retrieve remote metadata metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to ssh-repository (scpexe://mvn.metcarob.com:7456/public): Exit code: 1 - Connected to mvn.metcarob.com.
File "/public/metcarob/com/BobDiary/BobDiary/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml" not found.

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to retrieve remote metadata metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to ssh-repository (scpexe://mvn.metcarob.com:7456/public): Exit code: 1 - Connected to mvn.metcarob.com.
File "/public/metcarob/com/BobDiary/BobDiary/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml" not found.

    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:157)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to retrieve remote metadata metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to ssh-repository (scpexe://mvn.metcarob.com:7456/public): Exit code: 1 - Connected to mvn.metcarob.com.
File "/public/metcarob/com/BobDiary/BobDiary/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml" not found.

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.upload(DefaultDeployer.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:413)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:139)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to ssh-repository (scpexe://mvn.metcarob.com:7456/public): Exit code: 1 - Connected to mvn.metcarob.com.
File "/public/metcarob/com/BobDiary/BobDiary/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml" not found.

    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.MetadataTransportListener.transferFailed(MetadataTransportListener.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.upload(DefaultDeployer.java:417)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Exit code: 1 - Connected to mvn.metcarob.com.
File "/public/metcarob/com/BobDiary/BobDiary/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml" not found.

    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.external.ScpExternalWagon.executeScpCommand(ScpExternalWagon.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.external.ScpExternalWagon.get(ScpExternalWagon.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run(WagonTransporter.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTransporter.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get(WagonTransporter.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
    ... 32 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

The gist of the error message is:
File "/public/metcarob/com/BobDiary/BobDiary/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml" not found.

Of course this file isn't found. It is not in the repository as I am in the process of deploying it. I am expecting this process to create this file.
As this is the first time the jar is being deployed to any repository the file can no possibly exist.

The distribution part of my POM is:

```
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>ssh-repository</id>
            <name>ssh-repository</name>
      <url>scpexe://mvn.metcarob.com:71234/public</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

Are there any settings/methods that I have missed?

(I am running maven via eclipse m2e)

UPDATE:
Some extra information.
In my POM I have

```
  <!-- Enabling the use of SSH -->
  <extension>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
     <artifactId>wagon-ssh-external</artifactId>

     <version>2.10</version>
  </extension>
```

and my settings.xml is:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                          https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
      <localRepository/>
      <interactiveMode/>
      <usePluginRegistry/>
      <offline/>
      <pluginGroups/>
      <servers>
          <server>
              <id>ssh-repository</id>
              <username>maven_repo</username>
              <configuration>
                  <sshExecutable>plink</sshExecutable>
                  <scpExecutable>sftp</scpExecutable>
                  <sshArgs></sshArgs>
                  <scpArgs>-o UserKnownHostsFile=/home/robert/.ssh/known_hosts</scpArgs>
              </configuration>
            <!-- <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
            <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions> -->
          </server>
      </servers>
      <mirrors/>
      <proxies/>
      <profiles/>
      <activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

As far as I can see I have followed all the steps from http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ssh-external.html

Comment: I strongly recommend to use a repository manager to handle that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use a simple file system as a maven repository, no need to use a repository manager. I am using a amazon S3 and it works perfectly.

Additionally to the distributionManagement you have to declare a extension in maven, have a look at

[deploy-ssh-external](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ssh-external.html)

One more thing :

In the stacktrace you are using

```
scpexe://mvn.metcarob.com:7456
```

in the pom you use a different port

```
scpexe://mvn.metcarob.com:71234
```

This might be a problem, also.

Comment: Hi, the port thing is unrelated. I am using the method described in the document you linked but still getting the error.